# How to auto populate updated_by in abstract model that is used by all other models in my app?

Tags: django

I want to use abstract model to have all my common fields. How do I auto populate updated by. ?

I saw some old answers saying it is not possible to do in the model .
[DRY way to add created/modified by and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754485/dry-way-to-add-created-modified-by-and-time)

Anything changed+ in 5 years?

So far it looks like most easy way is  to use both decorator  django-author with Common model for other fields.

```
from author.decorators import with_author
@with_author
    class CommonInfo(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField("creation date", auto_now_add=True)
        modified = models.DateTimeField("modification date", auto_now=True)
        description = models.TextField()
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


        class Meta: and to have more control
            abstract = True
```

But the problem is that if I add decorator to abstract model I am getting error

> unit.Unit.updated_by: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for
>   'Unit.updated_by' cla shes with reverse query name for
>   'Tenant.updated_by'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Unit. updated_by' or 'Tenant.updated_by'.

To avoid it I have to add the decorator to each model instead .

Is it possible to   add the decorator to Abstract model somehow without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/), and how to handle QuerySets.

Look at the source code here (1.11), it may help you:

```
site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py
```